# Extracting number with letter from the address string in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, address, string

I have the following address examples to extract:

```
4A MANOR FARM CLOSE

38A OXFORD ROAD

56A BISHOPSTONE
```

and after using the following codes:

```
   regexp_substr( "Address L2", '(\\d*) ' )
```

or

```
   regexp_substr( "Address L2", '(\\d\\^*) ' )

   regexp_substr(
     replace( 
     "Address L2",
      regexp_substr("Address L2",'\\d\\s\\d') ,
     ''
     ),
     '(\\d+)'
   )
```

I am unable to extract the street number combined with the letter. I get the number only or just a blank space.

Is there any option to receive the street number concatenated with the letter like 19A 58C and so forth?

**UPDATE:**

Regarding the first answer, I have an error as you can see in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not good. when i.e. 12A occurs I get nothing in my field.

Comment: There is always a number+letter, a whitespace and something else? Are you saying there can be row with only **12A** in it?

Comment: your "Address 2" field seems to by of type Integer - and you want to fill it with letters and numbers. Change the column where you want your result to be into one of type "Text"

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than just in pictures.  That way they show up in searches and can be easily read on all devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option: 1**

The simplest way is to use the following regex expression:

```
regexp_substr("FieldName" , '^\\d+\\w+')
```

`^`: asserts position at start of a line.

`\\d`: matches a digit (equivalent to `[0-9]`).

`+`: matches the previous token between one or more, as many times as possible.

`\\w`: matches any word character (equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

The output will be as expected:

[image]

**Option: 2**

Another way is to explicitly select only letters with uppercase after numbers to avoid underscore `_` if exists:

```
 regexp_substr("FieldName" , '^\\d+[A-Z]+')
```

**Option: 3**

Another way is to create a custom function, name it `extract_numletter`, to split the address based on space and extract the first portion which is the numbers and letters as follows:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
def extract_numletter(text, feature, parent):
    numletter = text.split()[0]
    return numletter
```

Then from Custom Expression menu you can use the defined function as follows:

```
 extract_numletter("FieldName")
```

The output is the same as the above:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Execute (the number and letter must come first):

```
string_to_array("field", ' ', ' ')[0]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It could be good but I am getting an error: [] can only be used with map or array values

Comment: @MKR Copy and paste into your answer the row of the attribute table where the error occurred.

Comment: Question updated, see my approach

Comment: Yes, you were right. It was silly mistake, although the error still appears.

Answer (score 2):

For text field always formatted in the way you have it, this here is an alternative:

```
left ("Address L2", regexp_match( "Address L2", ' ')-1)
```

- It looks for the position of the first space in the initial string (using `regexp_match()`)
- Then the expression returns the string before that first space: the left part of the string using `left()` up until the character **before** the first string: for that `-1`

Answer (score 2):

In the [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) use the following expression:

```
array_first(string_to_array("Address L2", ' ', "Address L2"))
```

to get the output like this

[image: result]

Comment: I still have NULL instead of the number integrated with the letter. What is the most funny thing, none of examples provided work at this moment :(

Comment: Now I see where the error is. I set Address 2 as the integer only, which doesn't accept any letters. Hence nothing was working here.